# Manter cor da aba após clicar nela

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

Criei algumas abas, quando eu passo o mouse por cima de cada uma delas mostra a cor que eu mandei mas quando eu clico para abrir o conteudo da aba eu gostaria que mantivesse a cor, mostrando qual aba está aberta, em vez de voltar a cor original, alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Segue o css que eu estou usando:

```
.tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #C25C40;
        background-color: #262626;
        border-radius:5px;
        position:absolute;
        top:160px;
        left:360px;
        z-index:110;
    }


    .tab button {
        background-color: #262626;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        color: white;
        font: 600 13px Lato, sans-serif;
        opacity:0.9;
        z-index:110;
    }


    .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #C25C40;
        transition:.3s;
    }


    .tab button.active {
        background-color: #C25C40;
    }


    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        height: 670px;
        width: 605px;
        border: 1px solid #C25C40;
        border-top: none;
        color:white;
        background-color:#262626;
        border-radius:5px;
        position:absolute;
        top:189px;
        left:438px;
        z-index:110;

    }
```

EDIT: Segue também o HTML e o script que eu estou usando:

```
<div class="tab">
<button id="aba" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba1')">Contatos</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba2')">Contas</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba3')">Representante</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba4')">Grupos de Produto</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba5')">Reclamações</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba6')">Multi-Empresa</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba7')">Produtos</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab('aba8')">Qualidade</button>
</div>



   function openTab(aba) {

var theArray= new Array('aba1', 'aba2', 'aba3', 'aba4', 'aba5', 'aba6', 'aba7', 'aba8');
for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
    if(theArray[i] == aba){
        if (document.getElementById(aba).style.display=='none') 
        document.getElementById(aba).style.display='block';
        else
        document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Você usa algum framework para gerar as abas? Como está seu `HTML`?

Comment: Coloquei o html e o script que estou usando. Não, não estou usando framework.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) como também outros frameworks você pode facilitar seu trabalho, além é claro de configurar o estilo da forma que desejar. Segue exemplo de como deixar uma tab ativa entre outra opções:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Você pode editar as *tabs* da forma que desejar:**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```